# How do I manipulate Handler Mappings cleanly in IIS7 using the Microsoft.Web.Administration namespace?

Tags: c#, .net, iis, iis-7, iis-7.5

When manipulating Handler Mappings using the `Microsoft.Web.Administration` namespace, is there a way to remove the `<remove name="handler name">` at the site level.

For example, I have a site which inherits all the handler mappings from the global handler mappings configuration. In `applicationHost.config` the `<location>` tag initially looks like this:

```
<location path="60030 - testsite-60030.com">
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <authentication>
        <anonymousAuthentication userName="" />
      </authentication>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
</location>
```

To remove a handler I use code similar this:

```
string siteName = "60030 - testsite-60030.com";
string handlerToRemove = "ASPClassic";

using(ServerManager sm = new ServerManager())
{
  Configuration siteConfig = 
    serverManager.GetApplicationHostConfiguration();
  ConfigurationSection handlersSection = 
    siteConfig.GetSection("system.webServer/handlers", siteName);
  ConfigurationElementCollection handlersCollection = 
    handlersSection.GetCollection();

  ConfigurationElement handlerElement = handlersCollection
    .Where(h => h["name"].Equals(handlerMapping.Name)).Single();

  handlersCollection.Remove(handlerElement);
}
```

This results in the site's `<location>` tag looking like:

```
<location path="60030 - testsite-60030.com">
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <authentication>
        <anonymousAuthentication userName="" />
      </authentication>
    </security>    
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ASPClassic" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</location>
```

So far so good. However if I re-add the `ASPClassic` handler this results in:

```
<location path="60030 - testsite-60030.com">
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <authentication>
        <anonymousAuthentication userName="" />
      </authentication>
    </security>    
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ASPClassic" />
      <add name="ASPClassic" path="*.asp" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\system32\inetsrv\asp.dll" resourceType="File" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</location>
```

This can result in a lot of cruft over time for each website that's had a handler removed then re-added programmatically. Is there a way to just remove the `<remove name="ASPClassic" />` using the Microsoft.Web.Administration namespace code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have discussed this with the IIS product team and this appears to be a bug with the configuration system. What is more interesting is that when I attempt this code on Win7 with IIS 7.5, I cannot even re-add the handler programmatically. Attempting to do so results in a COM exception that states:

"Error: Cannot add duplicate collection entry of type 'add' with unique key attribute 'name' set to 'ASPClassic'"

That becomes even more problematic because once a user has "removed" a handler for a location, it cannot be re-added through the M.W.A. API until this bug is fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the response Tobin, now I know I'm not the only on being picky about this. Is it worth opening an issue on Microsoft Connect?

Comment: Yes. I'd say go ahead and open it up. The team already is aware of it, but it is well worth putting on Connect for tracking.

Comment: @Kev, 
Hi, i am also trying to do some similar thing, trying to remove handler mapping from a website in IIS7 using WMI . The code appears to be working fine but handler mapping is never removed. as i can see it inetmgr after removal. Please check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7102056/how-to-remove-handler-mapping-from-a-website-in-iis7-using-wmi-and-c-vb-net